# What will happen if I first pwrite then fwrite?

Tags: c, linux

What will happen if I first use pwrite and then fwrite on a file? I know with pwrite you can specify an offset to start writing. So will the fwrite write to the end of the file, or to the last position written by pwrite?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: `pwrite() writes up to count bytes from the buffer starting at buf to the file descriptor fd at offset offset. The file offset is not changed.` https://linux.die.net/man/2/pwrite

Comment: [`pwrite`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html) an [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) are totally unrelated. You really shouldn't mix OS-level file IO with C stdio.

Comment: Since `fwrite()` will be completely oblivious of the `pwrite()` operation, the next `fwrite()` will operate as if the `pwrite()` had not occurred, except that in append mode, if the `pwrite()` extended the file, `farite()` will end up writing after the new end of the file.

Comment: Note that on Linux, [`pwrite()` is broken](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html#BUGS).  If the file descriptor used for `pwrite()` is opened with the `O_APPEND` flag set, **the offset passed to `pwrite()` will be ignored and the data appended to the file**.  That **will** cause problems with your attempt to `fwrite()` to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

> So will the fwrite write to the end of the file, or to the last position written by pwrite?

Since you've tagged the question with `linux`, the answer is, "You can't do that."

If you're writing to the end of the file with `fwrite()` assuming you've opened the file in append mode, the underlying file will be opened with the `O_APPEND` flag set.  For example, this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    FILE *f = fopen( argv[ 1 ], "a" );
    return( 0 );
}
```

produces this `strace` output for the underlying ``openat()` call (Ubuntu 20):

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "asdf", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
```

Per [the Linux `pwrite()` man page **BUGS** section](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html#BUGS):

> **BUGS**
>
> POSIX requires that opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag should
> have
> no effect on the location at which `pwrite()` writes data.  However, on
> Linux, if a file is opened with `O_APPEND`, `pwrite()` appends data to
> the end of the file, regardless of the value of `offset`.

Comment: That's nasty (the divergent behaviour of Linux vs POSIX for `pwrite()`, that is).